# How to update attributes only if the params are defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, activemodel

currently in my update controller method I have:

```
@group.attributes = {
  :title => params[:group][:title],
  :description => params[:group][:description],
  :password_required => params[:group][:password_required],
  :password => params[:group][:password],
  :archived => params[:group][:archived]
}
```

The problem is that this method is used in multiple places and all of these params are not always passed which results in a "nil" which causes the db commit to rollback.

How can you set attributes only when they are defined w/o having to use if blocks?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could probably do something lousy like this:

```
@group.attributes = {
  :title => params[:group][:title] || @group.title,
  :description => params[:group][:description] || @group.description,
  :password_required => params[:group][:password_required] || @group.password_required,
  :password => params[:group][:password] || @group.password,
  :archived => params[:group][:archived] || @group.archived
}
```

This kind of ugly code is not recommended, but it answers the question of how to do this without explicit `if` blocks.

Answer (score 2):

why not simplify it with

```
@group.update_attributes(params[:group])
```

this way if the value us nil it wont be updated

Comment: That code saves the group, if you want to do some more processing before saving, you could do:
@group.attributes = params[:group]
# more code here... 
group.save
In fact, the update_attributes method is basically those two lines...